# Django Admin site, change models visibility for different users

Tags: django, permissions, admin, models

Suppose that i have that kind of situation. My django admin site has registered 3 models. I want that everything is visible for superuser, but if user is not a superuser i want to hide one model from him. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with permissions. Superusers always have all permissions, however, for each staff user individually you can choose which models they can change (and view), delete and create. This impacts directly what they can see and change in the admin interface. Also, you can specify groups, which have certain permissions, then when you assign a user to that group, it inherits the group's permissions (this is the more organized way to handle permissions).

More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/